# Playing sound in C++ using native system calls?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, unix, audio

So in Windows, you can use the `PlaySound` function to play an MP3 file in a C++ application. What would be some similar functions available for use in Mac OS X/Linux? I would also appreciate it if you could link to some sample Hello-World type programs demonstrating this.

Comment: You should consider using OpenAL for cross platform sound/music.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just `open("/dev/dsp")` and write to it.  That's as "native syscall" as you can get, I believe.

Comment: Im not sure if /dev/dsp is available on mac (by default at least)

Comment: Could you give me a working example? I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning Audio: Linux != Mac, so I will answer both separately.

MacOS uses the [core audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) framework for low level audio. Building on that there are several higher level APIs. If you just want to play a sound file the [AV Foundation Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html) is most likely the way to go. [Here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/create-a-basic-iphone-audio-player-with-av-foundation-framework) you find an example to build a simple app for iOS, which can be ported to MacOS easily.

For Linux the whole situation is quite delicate. There exist many different frameworks and libraries and it very unclear which is low and which is high level, since some of them are emulating the others. Basically there is ALSA and OSS for low level audio. Both of them are crap. Jack is aiming to provide a framework for professional audio but it's not very portable (at least if you are interested in embedded devices). Most Linux OS currently are using PulseAudio as their audio server, which has also a simple API for just playing a single sound and a very difficult API for low level stuff. And then there is the gstreamer library, which is rather portable and has a half way descent API and is especially designed for playing audio & video files and streams, and so probably the way to go on linux.

I personally recommend to use [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/), which is a library that provides – as the name states – an audio framework which is portable across several operating systems and [audio frameworks](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/api_overview.html). PortAudio is also well designed and has a simple but flexible API.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure if current desktops have some more advanced services/libraries that play audio files, but if you really want to do some low-level OS audio output, start looking [here](http://manuals.opensound.com/developer). Maybe this is a little too low-level for your needs.