# Unix audio system API

Tags: unix, audio

I would like to port a existing Windows application to Unix and I can't find certain information regarding Unix audio system and I would appreciate if anyone could share their experiences regarding this.

How can I:

- get all sound cards that are connected to the PC?
- get the sound card channel count?
- get the current sound card volume per channel?
- hook to the audio system and calculate the loudness of the sound that is being played (something like Windows 7 volume control - where it draws the "loudness" with a green bar). (I understand the math involved but looking if the system already provides a similar package)?

Is it possible to do this for every Unix system or do I have to do this for every system differently (on FreeBSD, Ubuntu...)?

Comment: Here is a similar Question with answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345766/playing-sound-in-c-using-native-system-calls/9349574#9349574

Answer (score 1):

Unix has a big mess of audio frameworks. You may end up having to do some work in a platform/framework dependent manner. I recommend to get started with PortAudio/PortMixer. It's used by Audacity, so hopefully it can cover most of your needs. But it should support the most common Unix variants like Mac OS X, Linux-Alsa, Linux-OSS, FreeBSD and I suppose a few more.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of different competing sound APIs on the various still-extant Unixes.

Linux seems to have converged on the [PulseAudio](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer) API for general-purpose sound output; my understanding is that this has similar capabilities to DirectSound.  You should also investigate [ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page), which is a lower-level API that is still widely used, and [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/), which is at the same level as PulseAudio but specifically geared for recording studio-type work.  These should be usable on all reasonably recent distributions of Linux.  (Note: if you are attempting to distribute *compiled code* for Linux as a third-party software vendor you are Doing It Wrong.  Distribute source, and the distributions will compile it for you.)

The documentation *says* PulseAudio and JACK also work on FreeBSD, but I don't know how *popular* they are there.  I don't know about any of the other BSDs or the remaining proprietary Unixes.

Stay away from anything calling itself "OSS," unless you have no alternative.  That was originally the name of an old, long-obsolete kernel-level sound API for Linux only.  A more recent attempt to resurrect it ("OSSv4") AFAICT has only managed to produce a zombie.

Comment: do you happen to know what would be the simplest way (which API) to get the sound stream (to calculate the loudness with digital signal processing) or even better sound "loudness" of the current audio?

Comment: No, sorry, I've never actually programmed with any of these.